# Show a customized message to the Web Visitor based on their IP

Tags: php, javascript, ip

I would like to be able to show a personal message to abusers of my webpage basd on their IP.  I run a Taxi booking site, But i keep getting few Visitors (always same IP range) who just book in fake bookings.

I would like to be able to send or show a message when they come to my site , so that they know that we are tracing their activities, any might give up there fake bookings.

Any way to do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: ip != person. use a proper user login/validation/control system

Comment: @Dagon: even though it would solve the issue, but barely anyone will register to book a taxi

Comment: @zerkms I have, maybe its just me, but i don't think so. This way they know my home address and i don't have to enter it every time, and know my list of destinations. I think most of us are use to signing up, if we want any kind of service from any website.

Comment: Why dont you add a capcha and validate the values passed and/or have new users based on a phone number validate there email address via a confirmation email where they have to click a link, then when they click and are returned to your site to confirm, make them confirm the phone number they added when making the booking. Also check its a real phonenumber and address ect. Or add what Dagon said...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '8.8.8.8') {
   print 'Go away';
}
```

A better idea is to do something more a long the lines of a [hell ban](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html) that way they won't figure out how to get around it. You do always risk effecting actual customers.

Comment: When Google's public DNS tries to book a cab, you pretty much know it's a fake...

Comment: maybe its the street view guy :-)

Comment: Technically I should have used 203.0.113.0 but it's a lot less memorable :P